# how to clear a timeout when the users screen's height is smaller then 250px in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am making a website and i want to clear a timeout in javascript when the user's screen height is smaller then 250px.here is the link for the [website](http://www.costtocost.unaux.com)  as the website is under developement stage please use chrome or firefox for browsing.The element which i want to remove is having a id of intro-div.

Comment: and your code is..?

Comment: so detect the size when the code runs. If it is less than the width, don;t run the code.... seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: if(window.screen.availHeight < 250){
  // do something
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read up on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing [mcve]s.

Answer (score 0):

// Start a timeout
var promise = $timeout(function() {}, 1000);

// Stop the pending timeout
$timeout.cancel(promise);

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle for that

Answer (score -1):

`if(window.innerWidth<=250) document.getElementById('intro-div').remove();`

or with css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:250px){
    #intro-div{ display:none; }
}
```